# How to increment a database entry?

Tags: php, mysql

The main problem is suppose i have a value stored in database = 26 now if the user does some action and i have to increse the value by 1 is there any predefined way in sql to do it.

Right now i am extracting the value then adding 1 then again updating the entry.

Comment: The approach given in the answer from Fluffeh avoids a concurrency problem, when two separate sessions are incrementing the value by 1, when both sessions pull the same value and add a 1 to it, the value only gets incremented by 1, rather than by 2. With the approach from Fluffeh, you are guaranteed that each session will increment the value by 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, run an SQL like below:

```
update yourTableName 
    set theColumnYouWant=theColumnYouWant+1 
    where yourConditions=YourConditionCriteria
```

A concrete example of the update syntax:

```
mysql> select * from first;
+------+-------+
| bob  | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
|    4 | NULL  |
|    5 | eeee  |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update first set bob=bob+1 where title='eeee';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from first;
+------+-------+
| bob  | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
|    4 | NULL  |
|    6 | eeee  |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Anandmohansinha I edited for an example shown from console as I was getting too many upvotes for the quality of the answer I gave :)

Comment: Your answer explains well how to increment a column value using the sql syntax, but the concrete example shouldn't probably be showcasing how to do it on the `id` column, as it may be misleading for some. The `id` column generally should be set to `autoincrement`.

Comment: @spider Good point - I used the test database I have open in my console at the moment. I have updated the answer to change the column name to make it less misleading (although you *can* change auto_increment fields manually if you want to).